# I want to display a PDF file in browser in pop up window

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

I want to display pdf in browser which is stored on sever ,i have tried this but  it displaying pdf in full screen. PLEASE HELP ME
java:

```
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    // use inline for view the content in browser, helpful for
    // pdf file
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath+filename);

    int i=0;
while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    out.close();    
    }
    catch (Exception e) {       
    }   
}
```

JSP:

```
<input type="submit" value="View PDF" name="submitbutton" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" />
```

Comment: Are you looking solution in Desktop application or web based  application?? Because you are using response object ??

Comment: i am looking for web application

Comment: in this case it should be better to give some info on the web app this code should run on.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602143/open-pdf-file-in-new-window-using-servlet

Answer (score 0):

If the PDF is a file on your filesystem, you can open it using the default PDF viewer with [`Desktop.open()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-).